# Django tutorial: unexpected indent error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, django-models

Here is my model.py code :

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        def __str__(self):
        return self.question


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

And when I run Following command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

this gives me following error:

> mjrulesamrat@mjrulesamrat-Lenovo-G570:~/django_local/first_web$ python
>   manage.py runserver Validating models...
>
> Unhandled exception in thread started by  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 93, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
>   line 98, in inner_run
>       self.validate(display_num_errors=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 310, in validate
>       num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py",
>   line 34, in get_validation_errors
>       for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
>   line 196, in get_app_errors
>       self._populate()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
>   line 75, in _populate
>       self.load_app(app_name, True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
>   line 99, in load_app
>       models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
>   line 40, in import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "/home/mjrulesamrat/django_local/first_web/polls/models.py", line 7
>       def **str**(self):
>       ^
>   IndentationError: unexpected indent

I'm using Django 1.6 and python 2.7.

Please guide me if i have made some mistake in this code. Cause when i run follow in python shell it gives me poll object not the question.

```
>>> Poll.objects.all()
[<Poll: Poll object>]
```

Comment: Read the last line of your error: `File "/home/mjrulesamrat/django_local/first_web/polls/models.py", line 7 def str(self): ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent`. Unexpected indent, on line 7.

Comment: It's easy to fix it. Instead of using space key, use tab. By the way, check your intendation after def __str__(self):

Comment: please don't degrade my question. I was fairly new to django so I made that mistake. Take back that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch/Fix your indentation on the model method level:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    # HERE 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # AND HERE
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```